# Disable constraint in postgres 10.6

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can anyone tell me how I can disable constraint in postgresql for all the tables in one go and enable it when needed ?

For example, I have 100 tables and I want to disable the constraint (one go) then perform some activity and enable them again.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you will have to delete that constraint, do your business, then add it back later.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen is there any other way to do this ? I wanted to avoid the approach of deletion

Comment: Constraints may be **deferred**. Read about it [in the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-constraints.html)

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention why you want to disable the constraints. You generally defined the constraints for a reason. Have you looked into deferred constraints? Deferred constraints might solve your use case.

The constraints are implemented as internal triggers in postgres and you can disable all the triggers for a table, run the statements you'd like to run without constraints and then re-enable the constraints.

Warning:

- If you have other triggers they will also be disabled
- Make sure the modifications don't violate the constraints

Here is an example:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;
DELETE FROM table_name ....;
ALTER TABLE table_name ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;
```

This needs to be done for all tables.